# React native: DNS Cache issue

Tags: react-native

I have migrated my server to a different host. The IP has changed and now some of the apps in production is not working(not everyone affected). Especially affected those who are using android with version less than 5(lollipop). Is this issue known or is it something else? I am using react-native v0.35.0

My question is somehow related with this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404)

From what i understand, this is related to name resolution, and the app is contacting the old server ip. Is there a way to fix this other than rollback to the old server ip?